# How can we validate multiple fields with one validation in cakePHP 2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp

how can we check firstname and last name is unique validation in cakePHP ?
record1:
first name :raj
last name: kumar

if we enter same name in input field , it should show validation message "Record alredy Exists".

i know how to validate single field validation.

how to validate that the combination of first_name and last_name is unique?

Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please state what version of CakePHP you are using. Are you asking how to validate that the combination of `first_name` and `last_name` is unique?

Comment: cakePHP2.x. yes.how can we validate combination of both fields?

Comment: Read the book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules You'll have to write your own rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to [setup a custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules) for testing that the 'full name' is unique. For example, in your model add a new method for validation like this:-

```
public function validateUniqueFullName(array $data) {
    $conditions = array(
        'first_name' => $this->data[$this->alias]['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $this->data[$this->alias]['last_name']
    );
    if (!empty($this->id)) {
        // Make sure we exclude the current record.
        $conditions[$this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey . ' !='] = $this->id;
    }
    return $this->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions)) === 0;
}
```

Then add the new validation rule to the model's `$validate` property:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'validateUniqueFullName',
            'message' => 'Not unique'
        )
    )
);
```

Where `'rule' => 'validateUniqueFullName'` instructs Cake to use the new validation rule to check that the name is unique.

You'll probably want to tweak/improve the above custom rule to meet your exact requirements but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: Really great . Thanks for providing answer.

Comment: How can we do the following statement in topics Controller with paginate?$posts=$this->Topic->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.topic_id'=>$id)));

Comment: Hi @arjun this isn't related to the existing question so please create a new one. :-)

Comment: yeah, When i tried to create new Question, it is showing that "reached my questions limit"

Comment: hi  drmonkeyninja, please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018417/how-can-we-do-the-following-statement-in-topics-controller-with-paginate

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public $validate = array(
    'facebook_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation','facebook_link'),
        'message' => 'Please enter facebook link.'
    ),
    'twitter_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation','twitter_link'),
         'message' => 'Please enter twitter link.'
    )

);

function customValidation($data , $filed) {
    if(empty($data[$filed])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```