# How can we do the following statement in topics Controller with paginate?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can we do the following statement in topics Controller with paginate?

```
$posts=$this->Topic->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Post.t‌​opic_id'=>$id)));
```

Here my intention is that join the Topics and Posts tables, retrive the no of posts where topic id is matching in the posts table using `paginate()` in cakePHP.

For example if topic id 1 have n no of posts. if change the topic id, that belongs posts will display using `paginate()`.

Comment: Have you tried anything for paginating them?

Comment: What is this line trying to do: $this->Topic->Post->find ?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [paginator component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#PaginatorComponent) rather than a `find`:-

```
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate(
    'Post',
    array('Post.t‌​opic_id' => $id)
);
```

The second parameter of `paginate` filters the result (*i.e.* these are the query conditions).

You can also pass the same sort of parameters to `paginate` as you would with a normal `find` using `$this->paginate`. For example:-

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Post.t‌​opic_id' => $id),
    'order' => 'Post.created DESC'
);
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');
```

In your case the first example should be sufficient.

Make sure you load the `Paginator` component in your controller:-

```
class PostsController extends AppController {    
    public $components = array('Paginator');    
}
```